# xrandr won't recognize HDMI

Tags: debian, nvidia, xrandr, hdmi

**System Spec**

OS: Debian 8 Jessie

Computer Model: ASUS G46V Laptop

Graphics Card: Nvidia Geforce GTX 660M (**This only seems to be an issue with my nvidia systems**)

Current Video Drivers: Nouveau

**Background**

Recently switched all computer systems to Debian Linux, had no issues with my other two systems. But this one appears to be giving me issues due to it's Nvidia Graphics card.

**Issue**

With Debian I am unable to recognize an HDMI port (xrandr can only see VGA and the Built in laptop Monitor)

I know it isn't a hardware issue because previously I had this system running dual monitors with Windows 10 (using both the HDMI and the VGA ports)

**lspci Output**

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GTX 660M] (rev a1)
```

**Xrandr Output**

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 2128 x 1024, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP1 connected primary 1360x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 309mm x 173mm
   1366x768      60.06 +
   1360x768      59.80*   59.96  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   640x480       59.94  
VGA1 connected 768x1024+1360+0 left (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 337mm x 270mm
   1280x1024     75.02 +  70.00    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.08*   70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    70.01    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    70.03    60.00
```

Non-Applicable References:

[HDMI not detected by `xrandr`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81822/hdmi-not-detected-by-xrandr)
In this scenario it was decided there was a hardware issue. However I've had this setup working with windows10

[xrandr doesn't detect monitor on hdmi port](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25120/xrandr-doesnt-detect-monitor-on-hdmi-port)
After trying this, I get an error message saying that cinnimon needs to restart, following the prompt leads to a cyclic error of restarts